# Assembly name in method return inherited class name

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

ok, you are correct that i didn't explain it very well.

I have client app and server WCF service. For transfering all data from client to server, I have 1 server API. That API expect dictionary for passing parameters. When I passing int, string, ... it goes well. But I can't do it the same with classes. Therefore I am using serialization of that class on client side and deserialization on server class. For deserialization I need to know type of class on server side. So I put parameter "AssemblyFullName" on BaseClass. All of my classes inherit from BaseClass.

For comunication with server, I have 1 method. Every comunication goes throw this method.

```
internal static void Execute(Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
    //finding type of object in parameters
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValuePair in parameters)
    {
        // problem row
        string fullName = keyValuePair.Value.GetType().FullName;
    }

    // rutine for comunication with server
}
```

My model looks like that and it is included on server and client side.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    private string AssemblyFullName { get; set; }
}

public class A : BaseClass
{

}

public class B : A
{

}
```

One method on client side expect "A" and comunicate with server.

```
public void ClientMethod(A expectedClass)
{
    Execute(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "identifierOfClassA", expectedClass } });
}
```

Calling of method "Execute" is always through "ClientMethod" in that type.

```
A a = new A();
ClientMethod(a);

B b = new B();
ClientMethod(b);
```

Point of this post is, why the row in method "Execute" return "namespace.A" or "namespace.B"? Why does not always return "namespace.A"? I call it from method "ClientMethod" that expect only "A".

Hope that will be more clear for you now.

Best regards Thomas.

Comment: The whole point of the `GetType` method is to allow you to get the runtime type of an object. You already know the compile time types of your variables/parameters, why are you trying to use runtime methods to try to get it?

Comment: Even if B inherits from A, B and A can be stored in different assemblies, so you can get different results depending on the context

Comment: You could make it Run up the inheritance chain to return the information regarding the parent type, but where would that end?  eventually everything inherits from `object`.  You'd be far better off posting what the actual *problem* you have is and asking for help there.  This looks like an X Y Problem to me... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Answer (score 2):

> Why second using return "B" instead of "A"? "AnotherMethod" expect "A". Is any way that method could return "A" in both examples?

Yes, of course there is:

```
public string AnotherMethod(A parameter)
{
    return typeof(A).FullName;
}
```

But that brings up some questions:

1. Why is the method named `GetAssemblyName` when you are returning the type's full name?
2. If you always want to return the full name of `A`, why do you even need `parameter`? Why do you even need a method? `typeof(A)` does just fine.
3. If you are trying something else, make the question clearer. As it stands now, its confusing.